# Is possible to save data form API once, save it on a variable and display it on demand on my node JS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Im new to node js.

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true)
  let answer =[];
  async () => {
    await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products').then(r => r.json()).then(d => {
      answer.push(JSON.stringify(d))
    })
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": 'text/html',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
  });
  res.end(answer);
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server Started');
```

Im trying to save the data in my array, once i get the info i should be able to render all data from that api.

Comment: First hint.  Stop using `async () => {  await someFunction() }()`.  That is a hack that is not necessary and since you left off the trailing `()` yours isn't even executing.  You don't need this here at all.   Do not use that construct.  Just declare your `http.createServer()` callback to be `async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. Your async IIFE with the `fetch()` in it is never called.
2. Even if it was called, you wouldn't be waiting for it.  You are trying to send your response before the `fetch()` has completed.
3. You are trying to send an array (that has JSON in it) with `res.end()`.  You can't do that.  You need to send text.
4. You are setting the content-type to text/html, but attempting to send JSON.  If you're actually going to send JSON, then set the content-type to `application/json`.

Change to this:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url')

http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true)
  const answer = [ ];

  const r = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
  const data = await r.json();

  answer.push(data);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
  });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(answer));
  
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server Started');
```

Summary of Changes:

1. The callback to `http.createServer()` is marked as `async` so we can directly use `await` in that callback function.
2. Remove `.then()` and just use `await`.  Don't mix `await` and `.then()`.  Pick one style or the other.
3. Push Javascript data, not JSON into the array.
4. Call `JSON.stringify()` on the whole array.  You can pass an array  to `res.end()`, you have to pass text.
5. Change content-type to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

One other tweak on this is that you only want the data to be fetched once, you can do this by pulling the data variable up to the module level, and checking for a value:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url')
 
let data;

http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true)
  const answer = [ ];

  if(! data) 
      data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products').then(r=> r.json())        
  answer.push(data);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
  });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(answer));
  
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server Started');
```

If you use something like lodash, you would memoize the fetch, or you could roll your own memoize function.